# Excel 2010 VBA/ADO connection error with XL source and text output

Tags: excel, vba, connection-string, ado

I am using Excel 2010 with a macro to access another daily spreadsheet to pull data for forming an FTP file of records. The specific problem I am having is a runtime connection error. The error I am getting is '-2147467259(80004005)': Unrecognized database format 'C:\Work\Daily FTP Process\Excel DBs and Files\ftp.xlsx'. All I need it to know where to look. Here is the connection string from the watch:

> : ConnectionString : "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Work\Daily FTP >Process\Excel DBs and Files\ftp.xlsx;" : String : Module1.XLFixedFieldFile

Here is the pertinent (or impertinent) code:

```
Dim conn As Object
Dim cmd As Object
Dim psidRecSet As Object
Dim loopIndex As Long
Dim connString As String
Dim sqlString As String

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
   & "Data Source=" & XLName & ";"
conn.Open connString    <==== Here is the line where it is breaking
```

Comment: Your connection string is wrong, get one here http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

Comment: Much thanks, Remou. That was a resource I hadn't found. I am still working on the connection string to get it to work, but the current state of the string is as follows:

Comment: Watch :   :     connString : "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Work\Daily FTP Process\Excel DBs and Files\ftp.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;" : String : Module

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED! The connectionstring that worked is as follows:

```
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & XLName & 
    "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';"
```

Remou, I had tried that, but had something wrong and got an error. The copy&paste of a working line found in another forum was my salvation. I appreciate the help.

For others using this yto solve their problems, to work with Excel 2010, I went to "Tools/Reference" and enabled Microsoft AcriveX Data Objects 6.1 Library and Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Recordset 6.0 Library.

```
    Dim conn As Object
    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" & XLName & 
    "';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1';"
    conn.Open connString
```

Comment: You do not need quotes around the data source, I tested with exactly the same name as you provided. Similarly, Excel 12.0 and Excel 12.0 xml both work. The only real difference as far as I can tell is XLName and xlfile variables. I suspect you do not have Option Explicit at the top of your page.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
 connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" _ 
 & xlFile & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=No;IMEX=1';"
```

Note the quotes for the extended property.

You might like to read http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819, with particular reference to IMEX.

Comment: Thanks again, Remou. I had started there, but it is good advice. I set the cursor to adOpenForwardOnly and adLockReadOnly, but the ADO converts it back to adOpenStatic. My current (minor) problem is that blank fields in Excel get read as NULLs. I am going to have to add a test for NULL before each imported field.